# C#, collection that holds Lists of different type

Tags: c#, list, collections, dictionary, hashtable

I currently have a class that holds 3 dictionaries, each of which contains Lists of the same type within each dictionary, but different types across the dictionaries, such as:

`Dictionary1<string, List<int>> ...`
`Dictionary2<string, List<double>>...`
`Dictionary3<string, List<DateTime>>...`

Is there a way to use a different collection that can hold all the Lists so that I can iterate through the collection of Lists? Being able to iterate is the only requirement of such collection, no sorting, no other operations will be needed.

I want to be able to access the List directly through the string or other identifier and access the List's members. Type safety is not a requirement but in exchange I do not want to have to cast anything, speed is the absolutely top priority here.

So, when calculations are performed on the list's members knowledge of the exact type is assumed, such as "double lastValue = MasterCollection["List1"].Last();", whereas it is assumed that List1 is a List of type double.

Can this be accomplished? Sorry that I may use sometimes incorrect or incomplete terminology I am not a trained programmer or developer.

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Given that each dictionary holds a different type of list, I would assume that each is intended for a different purpose. In that case, having three appropriately-named dictionaries seems clearer than having a monolithic, non-typesafe storage location. Is there a particular reason you'd like to have only a single dictionary?

Comment: the only reason being that I like to, as part of the whole project, dump all the Lists' contents into a Datatable and/or subsequent database table. In my current case the code is very clumsy because I always need to explicitly iterate through several dictionaries.

Answer (score 3):

To do that you would have to use a non-generic API, such as `IList` (not `IList<T>`) - i.e. `Dictionary<string, IList>`. Or since you just need to iterate, maybe just `IEnumerable` (not `IEnumerable<T>`). However! That will mean that you are talking non-generic, so some sacrifices may be necessary (boxing of value types during retrieval, etc).

With an `IList`/`IEnumerable` appraoch, to tweak your example:

```
double lastValue = MasterCollection["List1"].Cast<double>().Last();
```

You could, of course, write some custom extension methods on `IDictionary<string,IList>`, allowing something more like:

```
double lastValue = MasterCollection.Get<double>("List1").Last();
```

I'm not sure it is worth it, though.

Comment: One of the requirements was no casting. The top priority is speed here and thus I do not want to have to cast.

Comment: @Matt your requirements are conflicting - something has to go. A `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` only has one `TValue`.

Answer (score 0):

No, what you are trying to do is not possible; namely, the requirement for strong-typing on all of the lists without casting is what's preventing the rest.

If your only requirement is to iterate through each of the items in the list, then you could create your dictionary as a [`Dictionary<string, IEnumerable>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) (note the non-generic interface).  [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) derives from [`IEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) which would allow you to iterate through each item in the list.

The problem with this is that you would have to perform a cast at some point either to the `IEnumerable<T>` (assuming you know you are working with it) or use the [`Cast<T>` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) on the [`Enumerable` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx) (the latter being worse, as you might incur boxing/unboxing, unless it does type-sniffing, in which case, you wouldn't have a performance penalty).

I would say that you *shouldn't* store the items in a single list; your example usage shows that you know the type ahead of time (you are assigning to a double) so you are aware at that point in time of the specific typed list.

It's not worth losing type-safety over.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, I guess I thought I could just store the Lists (like different objects) in something, such as a hashtable or hashlist, and whenever a List is retrieved the type of the List is known. I guess I assume wrong then...